# SQL Basics If Column A is not empty then on Column B use

Tags: sql

Hi All just starting out with SQL. would like to ask.
For example if given:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Explanation:

- If column B is not empty the use Column B in Column E
- If Column B is empty then use column D in Column E
- If Column B and D is empty then leave  Column E as empty

How would you make this work in SQL?

Comment: Use `Coalesce(ColB, ColD)` for `ColE`.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

you can try using case statement as below:
select case b is not null then e=b else case d is not null then e=d else e=null end end

Answer (score 0):

You can use "case", like next query:

```
select t.colA, t.colB, t.colC, t.colD, 
       (case when t.colB is null and t.colD is null then null end
       else case when t.colB is not null then t.colB end end
       else t.colD end) colE 
from tabela t
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Coalesce, as stated in Siyual's comment:

```
select t.ColA
      ,t.ColB
      ,t.ColC
      ,t.ColD
      ,Coalesce(t.ColB, t.ColD) as ColE
from table t
```